# Javascript - Read textbox length

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the length of a textbox from my register form. I have tried using document.getElementById() and textbox.value.length. Is there something very simple I'm am missing. I alert the result to the screen to show the textbox length. Thanks in advance.

Here is my last attempt:

```
function Register(){
    Alert(RegisterForm.txt_Password.value.length);
}
```

TextBox structure:

```
<form id="RegisterForm" name="RegisterForm" method="POST" action="RegisterInsert.php" onsubmit="return Register(RegisterForm)">
                    <table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%">Email Address:</td>
                            <td width="85%"><input type="text" name="txt_Email" id="txt_Email"/> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%">Username:</td>
                            <td width="85%"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="user_name" id="user_id" class="user_name" >
                        <span class="check"  ></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%">Password:</td>
                            <td width="85%"><input type="password" name="txt_Password" id="txt_Password" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="btn_Register" id="btn_Register" value="Register"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </table>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </form>
```

I use the submit button to call the Register function.

Comment: When you say "textbox length", you mean length of the value string ?

Comment: @OlivierH Yes, sorry if didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the element first:

```
function Register() {
    var RegisterForm = document.getElementById('RegisterForm');
    alert(RegisterForm.elements['txt_Password'].value.length);
}
```

Comment: I had that without the single quotes. Such a silly mistake, thanks again.

Comment: and don't forget the extra line: `var RegisterForm = document.getElementById('RegisterForm');` where you grab a reference to the form first.

Comment: Yes, I realised that, I had just missed the single quotes on a previous attempt. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

**check out this code:**

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
var textLength = textBox.value.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('txt_Password').value.length);
```